# Working with subsets of the original data matrices for machine learning

Tags: pattern-recognition, bioinformatics, conv-neural-network

I have seen very educational applications of pattern recognition on complete images. I was wondering if there are methods that could handle cases with the following specifications:

- instead of full images we have a set of sub-images which are made by tearing the original image apart
- sub-images have arbitrary sizes (within a given range)
- some parts of the original image might be missing after tearing it apart

I am a newbie in this field but are there (could there possibly be) convolutional networks that can handle such cases? From what I understand they work by breaking the image down.

The answer for both these cases are helpful:
- Full size images for training and applying the classifier to torn-apart images 
- Torn-apart images for both training and testing

The answer for the both type of tasks to label each image (set of pieces) as a whole or to label each pixel in the image (~object recognition) would help me.

If you are not interested in bioinformatics don't mind this paragraph, but if you are interested, this question is the image-processing translation of my original question which is about phenotype-genotype mapping where I look at not fully assembled DNA sequences: we have contigs of reads rather than full sequences.

If you know some references that investigate this problem please advise me. Thank you very much for your input!

Comment: What you are looking for is called "compressed sensing".  You can, for some carefully controlled classes of images (dna sounds controlled, but I can't be certain), sample (uniform random) the image for a tiny fraction of its size, and still get recognition.  You have to account for pixel locations relative to each other, but it is much faster to operate on a few hundred pixels instead of tens of millions per image. [link](http://proceedings.spiedigitallibrary.org/proceeding.aspx?articleid=1354633)

Comment: If you like, I can put it into an answer.  Normally I feel like an bug among giants here, so if I am not sure what you are looking for, I feel a lot more comfortable putting the answer into a comment.

Comment: Indeed you pointed me to the right direction so  that counts as a right answer. I think stack exchange is about bigger bugs guiding smaller ones, thanks :D

Comment: I think it would help if you explained the actual bioinformatical problem more carefully. From my little knowledge of it,  I would think there were better analogies than image processing. Eg speech processing.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called "compressed sensing". You can, for some carefully controlled classes of images (dna sounds controlled, but I can't be certain), sample (uniform random) the image for a tiny fraction of its size, and still get recognition. You have to account for pixel locations relative to each other, but it is much faster to operate on a few hundred pixels instead of tens of millions per image.

http://proceedings.spiedigitallibrary.org/proceeding.aspx?articleid=1354633